# How can I prove that $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k\cdot P(n,k)}{n^{k+1}} = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

The answer is difficult to me, I cannot figure out how to compute it.

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k\cdot P(n,k)}{n^{k+1}}=1$

If someone can explain some technique to do it, I'd appreciate it. I tried to think of a combinatorics method but don't know how to build this model. Maybe I can use calculus?

Comment: What does $P(n,k)$ stand for? Permutations? Combinations?

Comment: @AlvinL it is common notation for the falling factorial...

Comment: Consider repeated random rolls of an $n$-sided die.  Interpret the terms in the sum as the probability that you see your first repeated value on the $(k+1)$'st roll of the die.  The sum of all such probabilities is equal to $1$.